# java.Statement.executeQuery() creates a prepared statement when it should not

Tags: javascript, java, postgresql, mirth

I have tons of code that looks like this:

```
conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;");
```

In my postgres logs I'm seeing tons of these lines:

```
parse <unnamed>: SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;
bind <unnamed>: SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;
execute <unnamed>: SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;
```

This is on a production server.

On my test server, I see:

```
execute <unnamed>: SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;
```

Which is what I expected to see on the production server.

Why the heck is it trying to create a prepared statement for my simple select query??

---

Some background:

- Mirth 3.4.1, connecting to Postgres 9.5
- My test case is in a Database Reader channel with "Use Javascript" checked off.
- But, from the logs, it appears every query is parse/bind/executed.  Even the internal queries that Mirth makes.

Comment: it could be the difference in log level settings

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's not actually creating prepared statements, but simple the log level settings is giving more detailed output?  If that was the case, wouldn't me running "SELECT a, b, c FROM foo;" from the postgres commandline give the same output in the log?  It does not.

Comment: Hey, this may be the answer (I'll need to check it out tomorrow): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741530/any-way-to-not-use-server-side-prepared-statements-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the PostgreSQL JDBC driver uses the extended protocol (parse/bind/execute) unless you force protocol version 2.

Usually the performance impact is small as the protocol messages tend to come in a single network packet, and it should not be a problem.

I'd think twice, test well and benchmark the performance difference before forcing protocol version 2. This old protocol version is not well supported and has started to smell funny. It has been seriously considered to remove support for it (see [this message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoYhaNPp6Lc5mG5%3D0_o8hFA3kqz32%3DuRX07kZgYsQ3uW0g%40mail.gmail.com) for a recent discussion).